# Ansible: Custom facts - error loading facts as JSON or ini

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

```yaml
shell> ansible ubuntu-c -m setup -m "filter=ansible_local"
...
```

I am trying to practice Ansible Custom facts: /etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact

```
#!bin/bash
echo {\""thing\"" : \""value\""}
```

But in keep getting this error:

```
"try": "error loading facts as JSON or ini - please check content: /etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact"
```

thought when i try to excute it using :

```
sh ./etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact
```

it returns the correct JSON format:

```yaml
shell> sh /etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact
{"thing": "value"}
```

Comment: Do not use images. [edit] the question and complete the [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#facts-d-or-local-facts), the file should be marked as executable if you want it to be executed, otherwise it is treated as a static file containing structured data. To test this you should be executing the file directly (`/etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact`), not passing it to `sh`.

```
chmod +x /etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact
/etc/ansible/facts.d/try.fact
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a simple playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_local
```

Both, *sh/bash* and the *python* [scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#facts-d-or-local-facts)

```sh
shell> cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/try-exe.fact
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s' '{"thing": "value"}'
```

```py
shell> cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/try-exe.fact
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print('{"thing": "value"}')
```

```yaml
shell> /etc/ansible/facts.d/try-exe.fact
{"thing": "value"}
```

work as expected

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_local:
    try-exe:
      thing: value
```

Also, static files both JSON and INI work as expected

```sh
shell> cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/try-json.fact
{"thing": "value"}
```

```sh
shell> cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/try-ini.fact
[default]
thing=value
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_local:
    try-ini:
      default:
        thing: value
    try-json:
      thing: value
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on creating custom-facts and this issue occurs when:

- The `/etc/ansible/facts.d/<factFileName>.fact`file is not executable
- The created fact file is not in the dictionary/JSON format

In your case, this issue is likely occuring due to the lack of executable permission on your fact file.